# Problems with Google Android Market (server error?)

Tags: android, google-play

I live in Austria and I tried to upload an updated APK to the Android Market, but couldn't load it up because the server could not load my APK (that's what their error message said, basically). After that I tried to change the description and save my changes and faced a "try it again later" error message.

Does anybody else face this problem today? Is it a bug at Google or what?

Comment: Could be a temporary error with Upload server.. Try after some time ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Market is back again - did updates of description and apk without any errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Australia and have been suffering this issue for about 8 hours. The Market also won't let me delete an inactive APK. So I'm assuming it is a fault at Google's end.

The error message received when I try and upload an APK is, "The server could not process your APK. Try again."

The error message when I try and delete the inactive APK is, "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me, I am unable to save any changes to the description ("An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.") or upload a new version of the APK ("The server could not process your apk. Try again.").

I believe it's a problem at Android Market. It has been like that for a while now, at least some hours. Hoping they'll fix the issue soon.

Comment: now I was finally able to start the upload - but it stopped after 512KB and seems to stay there forever. refresh doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem here in germany!

I receive an error message when I want to change the description and I did not receive any download's updates for my apps in the last 15 hours!

Answer (score 0):

It is time depend. Recently I made a lot of changes and update/upload my app every day. Don't spend the time to change anything in your apk. What you need is just open 10 different browsers with difference computer and keep uploading. Bump in! Every day, a successful upload come from thousand of fail and keep retrying more than 2 to 3 hours. Just think yourself as a robot and click like crazy! Don't need to login logout, clear cache, every extra work won't help but slow down your bumping. What you need is just keep trying. Just like you go to buy concert online ticket for a very famous pop star, you have to keep clicking until you get a place. And I don't know if it is a coincident upload seems easiler success at 00:00 GMT+00:00. I guess this is the office hour end of U.S. and their server become less busy.
And here are some statistic:
sucess rate:
Firefox: 1
Chrome:3
Safari:6
And once a success come up, all browser uploading at that moment will get a success. Obviously is server capacity problem.